# Disable/Enable h:commandButton on validation fails/ is ok

Tags: validation, jsf-2, form-submit

I got a TextBox with a validator and a commandbutton. When the validation of the textbox fails I want to disable the commandbutton otherwise it should be enabled. I don't want to use any codebehind so it should be working without any helper properties in the bean.

So how can I tell the commandbutton to be disabled/enabled depending on the validator state?

```
  <h:outputLabel for="category" value="#{msg['category.create']}"/>
                    <h:inputText id="category" required="true"  label="#{msg['category.create']}" value="#{CreateCategoryBean.newCategory.name}" >
                        <f:validator validatorId="Get.Validator.CategoryValidator" />
                        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="categorymessage"  />
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:messages for="category" id="categorymessage"/>

                    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="#{msg['default.create']}" action="#{CreateCategoryBean.CreateCategory()}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already a `<f:ajax event="keyup">`, just let it update the `<h:commandButton>` as well wherein you in turn in its `disabled` attribtue check if [`UIComponent#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) of `<h:inputText>` doesn't return `false`.

```
<h:inputText binding="#{category}" ...>
    <f:ajax ... render="categoryMessage submit" />
</h:inputText>

<h:commandButton id="submit" ... disabled="#{not category.valid}" />
```

No additional bean properties necessary. The above code is complete as-is.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works)